# In C - counting sequences of 1's

Tags: c, algorithm

Given a binary number such as "100001111111110000001" where each bit is placed in an array so that the array looks like the following:
[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

I want to locate the starting index and ending index of any sequence of 1's.

Desired output (reading from right to left):

-starting index = 0

-ending index = 0

(Get this numbers a do something accordingly)

Then:

-starting index = 7

-ending index = 15

(Get this numbers a do something accordingly)

last occurrence -

-starting index = 20

-ending index  = 20

(Get this numbers a do something accordingly)

How can I accomplish the desired output in C?

Attaching code I tried:

```
   for (int i = 0; i< counter; i++) {
    if (bitArray[i] == 0) {
      while (bitArray[i] == 0) {
        startP++;
        endP++;
        i++;
      }
    }
    if(bitArray[i] == 1) {
        startP++;
        while(bitArray[i+1]==1) {
          endP++;
          i++;
        }
    }
    if (endP == startP) {
        //do something
    } else if (endP == (startP + 1)) {
    //do something
    } else if (endP > (startP + 1)) {
    // do something
    }
    endP++;
    startP = endP;
 }
```

*counter = the len of the array

*endP and startP int, intiliazed.

*bitArray the array as described.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: yes attached the code

Comment: And what's the problem with the code? What does it print? Also, your code is not complete. Fix a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your code is supposed to do, but if you just want to print start and end indices of sets of 1s, I changed your code a bit to do so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char msg[64];

    int bitArray[] = {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};
    int inSet = 0;
    int start;
    int end;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(bitArray); i++) {
        if (bitArray[i] == 1 && inSet == 0) {
            inSet = 1;
            start = i;
        }
        else if(bitArray[i] == 0 && inSet == 1) {
            inSet = 0;
            end = i - 1;
            snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "-starting index = %d\n-ending index = %d\n", start, end);
            printf(msg);
        }
    }
    if(inSet == 1)
    {
        end = sizeof(bitArray) - 1;
        snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "-starting index = %d\n-ending index = %d\n", start, end);
        printf(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably need a statement after the `for` loop that sets `end` if `inSet == 1`. Also, you unnecessarily test `bitArray[i]` twice in every iteration of your loop. Use `else`.

Comment: I need to compare the staring index and ending index in the process, not printing them but rather checking in the iteration if the starting index is equal to the ending, or ending is greater than the starting index, according to that, do something else.

Comment: Well you have all the code to do so now, instead of the printf statement you can insert any statement you want.